# Why is this a compiler error? (g++)

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

So I'm attempting to utilize a generic compare functor in my utility class.

I attempt to define it and call it like so

```
template <class T>
bool AVL_tree<T>::avl_insert(AVL_Node<T> *& top, const AVL_Node<T> * insertNode, bool & taller) {
    std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::first_argument_type insertNodeValue;
    insertNodeValue  = insertNode->data;
    std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::second_argument_type topValue;
    topValue = insertNode->data;
    std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::result_type cmp_result;
    cmp_result = comparer(insertNodeValue,topValue);
    std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::result_type cmp_result2;
    cmp_result2 = comparer(topValue,insertNodeValue);
    //Function continues from here
}
```

The specific compiler error is expected ; before insertNodeValue

This error is repeated for topValue and cmp_result;

I don't really understand why this is a syntax error, I'm working off this reference:
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/binary_function/

Comment: Why all this: `std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::first_argument_type`? Instead of just `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dependent name, so it requires the `typename` keyword:

```
typename std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::first_argument_type insertNodeValue;
```

Similarly for others. See [the SO FAQ entry on dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names).

Answer (score 0):

Given that these are dependent types, your first step should probably be to add `typename`:

```
typename std::binary_function<T,T,bool>::first_argument_type insertNodeValue;
```